# Why is this Future never completing?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
class FileData {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    print('D: Local'); //D
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    print('D: Directory: $directory'); //D
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    print('D: Path: $path'); //D
    return File('$path/file.dat');
  }
  
  Future<File> _future;
  Future<RandomAccessFile> _futureRandomAccessFile;
  File _file;
  RandomAccessFile _randomAccessFile;

  FileData() {
    print('D: First'); //D
    _future = _localFile;
    _future = _future.then(
      (File file) {
        print('D: Stuff'); //D
        if(file == null) throw 'file == null';
        _file = file;
        print('D: Foo'); //D
        _futureRandomAccessFile = file.open(mode: FileMode.append);
        _futureRandomAccessFile = _futureRandomAccessFile.then(
          (RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile) {
            if(randomAccessFile == null) throw 'randomAccessFile == null';
            _randomAccessFile = randomAccessFile;

            print('D: Position: ${_randomAccessFile.positionSync()}'); //D
            int byte = DateTime.now().second; //D
            print('D: Write: $byte'); //D
            _randomAccessFile.writeByte(byte); //D

            return randomAccessFile;
          },
          onError: (e) {
            throw e;
          }
        ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 2));
        return file;
      },
      onError: (e) {
        print('D: Bad'); //D
        throw e;
      }
    ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  _syncRandomAccessFile() {
    while(_randomAccessFile == null) {
      print('Waiting on _randomAccessFile...');
    }
  }

  void close() {
    _syncRandomAccessFile();

    print('D: Position: ${_randomAccessFile.positionSync()}'); //D
    _randomAccessFile.setPositionSync(0); //D
    print('D: Position: ${_randomAccessFile.positionSync()}'); //D
    print('D: Byte: ${_randomAccessFile.readByteSync()}'); //D
    int byte = DateTime.now().second; //D
    print('D: Write: $byte'); //D
    _randomAccessFile.writeByte(byte); //D

    _randomAccessFile.close();
    _randomAccessFile = null;
  }
}

FileData fileData;
```

And this in my app home page state:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fileData = FileData();
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
    fileData.close();
  }
```

I would expect the following sequence of events:

```
D: First
D: Local
(some or none) Waiting on _randomAccessFile...
D: Directory: <whatever>
D: Path: <whatever>
D: Stuff
D: Foo
(some or none) Waiting on _randomAccessFile...
D: Position: <whatever>
D: Write: <whatever>
D: Position: <whatever>
D: Position: 0
D: Byte: <whatever>
D: Write: <whatever>
```

Instead, I get:

```
D: First
D: Local
(a lot of) Waiting on _randomAccessFile...
(app freezes)
```

I do not understand why this should be the case. I obviously need the file to be open before reading/writing/closing it, and I need it in an instance variable to be able to use it both in synchronous and asynchronous code. My understanding is that the future returned by `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` never completes for some reason.

I expect this to be some fundamental misunderstanding I've had, more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sleep` call does not what you expect since it does not allow running asynchronous operations.

> Sleep for the duration specified in duration.
>
> Use this with care, as no asynchronous operations can be processed in a isolate while it is blocked in a sleep call.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/sleep.html

Also, it is not a great idea to have asynchronous operations inside a constructor since you cannot be sure when the object are fully created. Instead, make a static method inside `FileData` which can return `Future<FileData>` and has the purpose to execute all the asynchronous operations before returning the fully constructed object. By doing so, you don't need to `sleep`.

Comment: Okay, thank you! The `sleep` call is probably not the main problem since the operations could complete while the polling loop is running, but that issue with using async operations inside a constructor... I sure wasn't aware of that. Where could I find more info on where async code is or isn't safe? Edit: yeah, the problem still happens if I remove that `sleep`...

Comment: It makes sense you still got the problem after removing the sleep. Your code are doing the same operations with or without the sleep but with the sleep, you are doing nothing for some time and then resume the operation. You need to allow the async code to run and you can only do that if you `await` the returned future. Please read https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await and https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

Answer (score 0):

julemand101's comment gave the answer to this question. Just in case someone finds this and is looking for a detailed explanation of what I learned from it...

Dart is single-threaded. Async operations are only completed when the current operation completes and control returns to the event loop. `await` somehow makes sure that this happens. It would also happen if I had put that `fileData.close()` in a different function that got called from the event loop. But I called the constructor and then waited for the future to complete without returning control to the event loop in between, so the future never completed and it just locked up forever.